# How do I install qemu on Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: apt, qemu

I performed a minimal install of Ubuntu 23.10 on a typical desktop PC (x64). I've made no changed to `/etc/apt/sources.list` from the default. I want to set up some VMs, so I typed:

```sh
sudo apt install qemu
```

like I've done in the past, and like many online sources suggest. But I got this error:

```
Package qemu is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'qemu' has no installation candidate
```

How can I install qemu?

Comment: QEMU is in `universe` now, you'll have to enable it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: No. The `universe` repository was already enabed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For full system emulation run: `apt-get install qemu-system`

For emulating Linux binaries run: `apt-get install qemu-user-static`

**That is quoting this Source:** (https://www.qemu.org/download/#linux)

Apparently, it is assumed the user knows this must be done with root privilege, e.g. :

`sudo apt-get install qemu-system`

The more modern way is to run:

`sudo apt install qemu-system`

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu, like most binary Linux distributions, splits QEMU into a few dozen actual packages because QEMU is *huge*, almost nobody actually needs all the components, and some of the components are actually a potential security risk. There used to be a `qemu` metapackage that pulled in everything, but it got removed long ago because, as mentioned above, almost nobody actually needs everything.

The package you actually want here is almost certainly one of:

- `qemu-system-<arch>` to run regular virtual machines for `<arch>` (If you just want to run native VMs, replace `<arch>` with the output of `uname -m`). In this case you may also want `qemu-system-gui` if you intend to use QEMU’s built-in GUI to access the VM console from your desktop or `qemu-utils` if you need to be able to manipulate disk images. Alternatively, `qemu-system` will pull in *all* of the full system emulators.
- `qemu-user-static` to use QEMU’s userspace emulation to run non-native binaries or containers, and possibly also `qemu-user-binfmt` to get automatic setup of this functionality.
- `qemu-utils` if you’re just looking for the `qemu-img` or `qemu-nbd` tools.